# Whitelist disks to mount in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mount, automount

Is it possible to make a white list of disks to mount? I have multiple systems on multiple drives and I would prefer not to mount everything all the time. I can unmount it afterwards, but that is not just as elegant.

I would imagine some magic in com.apple.boot.plist or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended method [I found](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060930150059172) indicates you should use entries like the following in your /etc/fstab file to prevent mounting:

```
UUID=FAB060E9-79F7-33FF-BE85-E1D3ABD3EDEA  none     hfs    rw,noauto
```

As I understand it, entries for known discs will be treated preferentially by their fstab entry over any automount/other behaviors.

Also, according to the linked information, you should be able to use the following to determine disk/partition UUIDs:

```
diskutil info /path/to/disk
```

On hindsight, this isn't really a "whitelist" operation so much as a "blacklist" operation, but it is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: Awesome finding, I actually did not believe it is possible. Thanks, awarding the bounty as soon as it's ready.